# Detecting when an element is about to get focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, focus, radeditor

I have an ASP.NET page with a Telerik RadEditor (rich text box). When tabbing through a page, when a user gets to the text box, focus gets set to the various toolbar icons before it goes to the textarea. I added some jQuery to one page to set the focus on the text area when tabbing out of the last cell on a form:

```
$('input[type=text][id*=tbCost]').keydown(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 9) {    //If TAB key was pressed
        e.preventDefault();
        var editor = $('body').find("<%=RadEditor1.ClientID%>");    //get a reference to RadEditor client object
        editor.setFocus();    //set the focus on the the editor
    }
});
```

I am looking for a way to implement this functionality in the control so that it will work regardless of the page it is on. For example, in the above code, focus is only set if the user is tabbing out of the `tbCost` cell. I would like to be able to set the focus to the text area when a user tabs into the toolbar items.

Is there any way to detect when an element is *about to get* focus? I know I can see if an element *has focus*, but I can't think of a way to implement this functionality.

Thanks

**Solution:**

If anybody has this same question in the future and wants an example, here is the code I used:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.reToolCell').focusin(function () {
        var editor = $('body').find("<%=RadEditor1.ClientID%>");
        editor.setFocus();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not set focus on `keyup()`?

Comment: you could use JQuery's "bind" or "on" methods to bind this particular code to all input[type=text] elements

Comment: @rnirnber I think using `on` could work. Can I do something like this to shift the focus when the toolbar (`.reToolCell`) gets the focus?: `$('.reToolCell').on('focus', function(){ var editor = $(this).find("<%=RadEditor1.ClientID%>");editor.setFocus(); });`

Comment: well "$find" would really be $(this).find...but yeah other than that it looks good, i do stuff like that all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider binding to a focus on the toolbar icons and redirecting focus to the text area. Although this might have unintended side effects if users are trying to tab-focus these tools in order to use them.

Comment: I agree that it might cause problems if users are trying to tab focus to the toolbar, but it looks like this will work overall. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    //on focus eventHandler for all your icons that calls a function


  #('.elementtype, class or a generic way of identifying the icons'.onfocus(myFunction(this))
```

//the function take a parameter of your element, moves to the next sibling element and sets the focus

```
     myFunction = (element) {
       element.next().focus();
     }
```